# Changing text value with Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

New to Kotlin, I've followed the guide on how to set up a basic "Press the button and it changes text" However Whenever I press the button, the app crashes and in the debugger I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
                                on a null object reference at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.One(MainActivity.kt:16)
```

Here is my current MainActivity.KT:

```
    package com.example.myapplication
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.TextView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    
        fun One(view: android.view.View) {
           val onetext = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
            onetext.text = "Hello"
        }
    }
```

And my activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="One"
            android:text="Button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="462dp" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the problem is that you're using `view.findViewById()`.
If you remove the `view.` it will probably work.  But since you're using synthetics you can remove the `findViewById()` call and just set the text directly as in `textView.text = "Hello"`.  Also note that using kotlin synthetics is deprecated and should be replaced with view binding.

Comment: This resolved it. Knowing the things im using are depreceated  ill be on the look out for a new guide. I really appreciate it. I will be more than happy to mark your answer as correct if you recomment it as an answer

Comment: I didn't notice the synthetics, nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `onetext` is null, which means `view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)` didn't find a view with `textView` as id inside of `view`. The `view` passed in the function is the `button`, which has no `textView` as a child. You need to search for the `textView` in a view higher in the hierarchy.

In the specific example, one way of doing that is by omitting the `view` receiver, like so:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun One(view: android.view.View) {
       val onetext = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
       onetext.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

This way it will search for the `textView` id in the Activity's view, which is the activity_main layout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem has already been solved, but I noticed that in the xml file the button is not properly docked, putting:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
```

the button would be below the TextView component and putting:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

the button would be centered on the screen...

Button code would look like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="One"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```